# Monthly savings calculator in Java

Tags: java, arrays

**EDITED TO FIX THE RECURSIVE METHOD.

I am working on some homework to create a program that randomly generates monthly savings amounts for 15 individuals. Each monthly saving should be in the range of $100 to $800 and is put into a savings account with an annual interest rate of 5%. Thus, the monthly interest rate is 0.05/12 = 0.00417. All the amounts are supposed to run for 12 months.

I have created the following class to perform the requested functions:

```
public class EmployeeSavings extends AddressBook {

    private double accountValue;
    private double[] monthlyInterests;
    private double[] monthlySavings;
    public static final double ANNUAL_INTEREST_RATE = 0.05;

    /**
     * Using the superclass constructor with args (fn, mn, ln), create a new
     * instance of class EmployeeSavings. Initialize instance variables to
     * values of the arguments passed through the constructor parameters. All
     * parameters defined through the variable list are defined in this
     * instance.
     *
     * @param fn - first name of the employee.
     * @param ln - last name of the employee.
     */
    public EmployeeSavings(String fn, String ln) {
        super(fn, " ", ln);
    }

    /**
     * Using the superclass constructor with args (fn, mn, ln), create a new
     * instance of class EmployeeSavings. Initialize instance variables to
     * values of the arguments passed through the constructor parameters. All
     * parameters defined through the variable list are defined in this
     * instance.
     *
     * @param fn - first name of the employee.
     * @param ln - last name of the employee.
     * @param d1 - monthly savings of the employee.
     * @param d2 - monthly interests of the employee.
     */
    public EmployeeSavings(String fn, String ln, double[] d1, double[] d2) {
        super(fn, " ", ln);
        d1 = monthlySavings;
        d2 = monthlyInterests;

        System.out.println("Savings: ");
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(monthlySavings));
        System.out.println("Interests: ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(monthlyInterests));
        System.out.println("The total account value is: ");
        System.out.println(accountValue);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static String getReport(EmployeeSavings[] arr) {
        for (EmployeeSavings arr1 : arr) {
            System.out.println("First name: " + arr1.getfirstName());
            System.out.println("Last name: " + arr1.getlastName());
            System.out.println("Account Value: " + arr1.accountValue());
        }
        return "This is your report.";
    }

    public double getAccountValue() {
        for (int i = 0; i < monthlyInterests.length; i++) {
            accountValue = (accountValue + monthlyInterests[i] + monthlySavings[i]);
        }
        return accountValue;
    }

    public double[] calculateInterests() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            monthlyInterests[i] = (monthlySavings[i] * (0.05 / 12));
        }
        return monthlyInterests;
    }

    public double[] generateMonthlySavings() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            monthlySavings[i] = (Math.random() * 700 + 101);

        }
        return monthlySavings;
    }

    public double[] getMonthlyInterests() {
        return monthlyInterests;
    }

    public double[] getMonthlySavings() {
         return monthlySavings;
    }
}
```

My main method, meanwhile, looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] d1 = new double [12];
    double[] d2 = new double [12];

    EmployeeSavings [] employees = new EmployeeSavings[15];
    employees[0] = new  EmployeeSavings("Elena", "Brandon", d1, d2);
    employees[1] = new  EmployeeSavings("Thomas", "Molson", d1, d2);
    employees[2] = new  EmployeeSavings("Hamilton", "Winn", d1, d2);
    employees[3] = new  EmployeeSavings("Suzie", "Sarandin", d1, d2);
    employees[4] = new  EmployeeSavings("Philip", "Winne", d1, d2);
    employees[5] = new  EmployeeSavings("Alex", "Trebok", d1, d2);
    employees[6] = new  EmployeeSavings("Emma", "Pivoto", d1, d2);
    employees[7] = new  EmployeeSavings("John", "Lenthen", d1, d2);
    employees[8] = new EmployeeSavings("James", "Lean", d1, d2);
    employees[9] = new EmployeeSavings("Jane", "Ostin", d1, d2);
    employees[10] = new EmployeeSavings("Emily", "Car", d1, d2);
    employees[11] = new EmployeeSavings("Daniel", "Hamshire", d1, d2);
    employees[12] = new EmployeeSavings("Neda", "Bazdar", d1, d2);
    employees[13] = new EmployeeSavings("Aaron", "Smith", d1, d2);
    employees[14] = new EmployeeSavings("Kate", "Hen", d1, d2);

    EmployeeSavings.getReport(employees);

    }

}
```

Now instead of returning forever, I'm getting null values as my outputs, for example:

First Name: Elena
Middle Name:
Last Name: Brandon

Savings: 
null
Interests: 
null
The total account value is: 
0.0

Any idea how I can get the randomly generated values in my methods to pass through to the "getReport" method? Or are those methods not outputing right in the first place?

Thanks!
B

Comment: **WHAT** ArrayList??

Comment: Your `getReport` method returns itself, an infinite recursive statement that will throw a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: `EmployeeSavings.getReport(arr);` is an infinite recursive method

Comment: EmployeeSavings extends AddressBook? How can an EmployeeSavings possibly be an AddressBook? That makes as must sense to me as Banana extends HairDryer. Also, if you accumulate interests every month, the monthly rate is not the annual rate divided by 12.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, the title was off before. And as for the class extension, well that's the way the homework asks for us to build the class (I think so we can use the getters from the AddressBook class for the person's first and last name). Not my choice!

Comment: In your main method, what are the values in d1 and d2?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
System.out.println("Account Value: " + arr1.accountValue);
```

with:

```
 System.out.println("Account Value: " + arr1.getAccountValue());
```

I think this is the problem.

Anyway, in the constructor

```
public EmployeeSavings(String fn, String ln, double[] d1, double[] d2)
```

You instantiate again monthlySavings and monthlyInterests, I do not know if it is a thing you want or not but you are re-instantiate them 
after associating them with d1 and d2